# BxSlider on bootstrap 3 tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bxslider

I want to show a bxslider carousel on a second tab of bootstrap. I have used the following to get the bxslider to show.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#more-info a.a-tab").one("click", function (e) {
        var tab_id = jQuery(this).html();
        if (tab_id == "this_is_title_of_div") {
            var slider = jQuery(".bxslider_div");
            if (slider) {
                jQuery(".bxslider_div").show();
                jQuery(".bxslider_div").bxSlider({
                    slideWidth : 300,
                    minSlides : 1,
                    maxSlides : 3,
                    moveSlides : 1,
                    slideMargin : 10,
                    pager : false
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

The problem is I want to load it once and not load it again when I click it. The carousel is completely broken on this tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a stat for your bxslider init. Do a check before initiating it and set the stat as true.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var tabInitiated = false;

    $("#more-info").on("click", "a.a-tab", function (e) {
        if($(this).text() == "this_is_title_of_div"){
            $(".bxslider_div").show();

            if(!tabInitiated){
                $(".bxslider_div").bxSlider({
                    slideWidth : 300,
                    minSlides : 1,
                    maxSlides : 3,
                    moveSlides : 1,
                    slideMargin : 10,
                    pager : false
                });
                tabInitiated = true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello Ashish unfortunately its still not working... its collapsing all the slides and giving an ugly look on the second tab. Is there no simple fix on a bootstrap 3 tab. thansk alot though.

Comment: The slider becomes a slim strip with height 0 and the two direction arrows visible.if i click on the firebug in mozilla firefox all the slides get their heights but they are all heaped on one another.with now width 100.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Ashish it was out of your fix that i coined this. this seemed to do it

```
         jQuery(function(){
         var tabInitiated = false;
    jQuery("more-info a.a-tab").on("click", function (e) {
    if(jQuery(this).text() == "this_is_title_of_div"){
        if(!tabInitiated){
        alert(tabInitiated);
         jQuery(".bxslider_div").show();
         jQuery(".bxslider_div li").css("height", "375px");          
            jQuery(".bxslider_div").bxSlider({
                slideWidth:1100,
                            auto: true,
                            autoControls: true,
                            slideMargin:20  
            });
        jQuery(".bxslider_div li").css("width", "1100px");  
            tabInitiated = true;
        }
    }
});
```

});

So i eventually gave the list a height and width attributes. But you have to give the width attributes once the bxslider has loaded. Thanks alot for your lead. I also found this link that can assist someone else http://www.aeonlighting.url.tw/en/tt.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".tabs-1").click(function() {
    $('#tabs-1 .bx-viewport').css("height","433"); 
    $('#latest_pros .dishes-item').css("width","245"); 

});
$( ".tabs-2").click(function() {
    $('#tabs-2 .bx-viewport').css("height","433"); 
    $('#latest_pros .dishes-item').css("width","245"); 

});
$( ".tabs-3").click(function() {
    $('#tabs-3 .bx-viewport').css("height","433"); 
    $('#latest_pros .dishes-item').css("width","245"); 

});
demo http://indiawings.co.in/
[http://indiawings.co.in/][1]
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code. [Edit] your answer and explain why this is the solution